# setting a "checkpoint" in Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am using Python 2.7 with Pycharm and I am working on a quite large text files; they are about 3gb in total.

I need to run LDA, PoS tagging, and other feature extraction methods on the data from the file but everytime I test my code, it has to read the file and go through the same process all over again from the beginning.

This is why I often use Jupyter because all the data / variables in previous cells are kept in memory.

Is there any way to do something similar with Pycharm?
For instance, let's say I am adding features to `do_some_feature_extraction()`

```
def do_some_feature_extraction(str_list):    
    # feature extraction 1   
    # feature extraction 2

str_list = []
with open("some_file.txt", "rb") as f_in:
     for line in f_in:
          str_list.append(line)

do_some_feature_extraction(str_list)
```

Let's say, there was an error on "feature extraction 1" and then I fixed it.
Then I will run the code again, then there will be another error on "feature extraction 2". Then I will fix it and run the code again from the beginning.

Instead of doing this, can I just set some sort of checkpoint before executing `do_some_feature_extraction(str_list)` ?

Comment: Joblib has a Memory class that does exactly this, although loading the checkpoint may also take a long time. I develop in PyCharm, then use a Jupyter notebook with the auto reload extension to put the code I wrote together.

Comment: @mbatchkarov this is good!! I had to restart the kernel everytime I made changes to my other codes, and it was really troublesome

Answer (score 1):

click the left side of your code ... next to the line number(or where the line number would be if you have them turned off)

[image]

a red dot should appear (this is called a breakpoint)...

[image]

now run it in debug mode

[image]

when you reach your breakpoint you can click the console tab

[image]

and then click the interactive terminal button(>_) to work directly with the context of the program

[image]

Comment: then instead of writing directly into the file right away, I should test the codes on the console first, then move it to the file?